# Firebase Web Push Custom Chrome Badge

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

This topic is well covered on Android and iOS (ANCS) however it is not discussed in any documentation for Web notifications.

My goal is to create a custom Chrome notification badge for mobile (see image below). I would have thought it was as simple as setting a field in `web.manifest.json` or in the `payload` sent to FCM but these have no effect.

I found some interesting discussion around a `badge` and `purpose` field for web manifest here - https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/480 but does not appear to be in use by Chrome.

[image: Custom Chrome badge]

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for a complete explanation on how making badges work on chrome PWAs. It explains the file format for the badge image itself as well as the format of the message payload.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688393/11222505