# Changing the chrome badge on web push notification sending with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, curl, service-worker

I am having an issue with om my code about changing the badge (the small icon) on web push notification.

There is [this wonderful site](https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator) that shows the live example and also displays source code.
I couldn't figure out why there he was able to change the badge and I didn't. I did a broad search on the Internet and couldn't find a solution.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$YOUR_API_KEY = MY_KEY;

$YOUR_TOKEN_ID = THE_CLIENT_TOKEN;

$request_body = [
    'to' => $YOUR_TOKEN_ID,
    'notification' => [
        'title'         => 'Title test',
        'body'          => 'Body Test',
        'icon'          => 'https://tests.peter.sh/resources/icons/4.png',
        'click_action'  => 'https://www.google.com',
        'badge'         => 'https://i.imgur.com/9QFB20F.png',
        // 'badge'      => 'https://tests.peter.sh/resources/icons/11.png',
    ],
    'data' => [
        // 'Nick'           => 'Mario',
    ],
];

$fields = json_encode($request_body);

$request_headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=' . $YOUR_API_KEY,
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//echo $response;
?>
```

When I send notification from 'peter.sh' Notification Generator site I got this badges, like i want (on my android phone):

[The badges as shown by peter.sh site, and just as I want them to be displayed on mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9xwD.jpg)

But when I send it with my code I get the **regular chrome badge**:

[The badges as shown on my site when I can't change them from chrome badges to mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVwUH.jpg)

Why the badge doesn't change according to my code? I am sending the badge property...

Comment: Have you tried with another image? Have you tried to host the image on your domain?

Comment: Yes. Like you see at my code I tried a few url-s...

Comment: Anyone can help? :/

Comment: did  you solved this?

Comment: no…  not yet… :(…

Comment: I need solution, either...

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for a complete explantion on how to make badges on chrome PWAs work. It specifies the image format of the badge image as well as the required message payload.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688393/11222505