# FCM Push notifications arrive twice (Nuxt with firebase)

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxt.js

So I searched here about this problem and I saw many experienced it but still didn't find solution.
[FCM Push notifications arrive twice if the browser is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690124/fcm-push-notifications-arrive-twice-if-the-browser-is-in-background?rq=1)
Ty for your help.

My nuxt config firebase serviced:

```
   services: {
  auth: true, // Just as example. Can be any other service.,
  messaging: {
    createServiceWorker: true,
    fcmPublicVapidKey: "###", // OPTIONAL : Sets vapid key for FCM after initialization
    inject: fs.readFileSync("./serviceWorker.js")
  }
}
```

my service worker:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log("[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ");
  self.registration.hideNotification();

  return null;
});

self.addEventListener("push", function(e) {
  data = e.data.json();
  const options = {
    tag: "notification-1",
    body: data.notification.body,
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: "1"
    }
  };
  self.registration.showNotification(data.notification.title, options);
});

self.addEventListener(
  "notificationclick",
  function(event) {
    console.log("test", event);
    event.notification.close();
    const url = "home";
    event.waitUntil(
      self.clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then(windowClients => {
        // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
        for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
          const client = windowClients[i];
          // If so, just focus it.

          if (client.url === url && "focus" in client) {
            return client.focus();
          }
        }

        if (self.clients.openWindow) {
          console.log("open window");
        }
      })
    );
  },
  false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  self.registration.hideNotification();
```

On top of line

```
self.registration.showNotification(
```

This allows your app to hide the default notification in which case you will only have one notification.